# Finding Auto Incremented values from an INSERT OR IGNORE statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I have a table called "images":

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    url     TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    caption TEXT
);
```

On inserting a row, I'd like the URL column to be unique. At the same time, I'd like to find out the id of the row with that URL.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE images (url, caption) VALUES ("http://stackoverflow.com", "A logo");
SELECT last_insert_rowid(); -- returns the id iff there was an insert.
```

Of course, I'd like to do it as quickly as possible, though my first thought was along the the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
int oldID = execSQL("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE images (url, caption) VALUES ('http://stackoverflow.com', 'A logo')");
int newID = execSQL("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
if (newID != oldID) {
     // there was an insert. 
     return newID;
} else {
     // we'd already seen this URL before
     return execSQL("SELECT id FROM images WHERE url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'");
}
```

But this seems hopelessly inefficient.

**What is the most performant way of getting the Auto incremented row id from an INSERT OR IGNORE statement.**

Answer (score 1):

In Android 2.2 you can use `SQLiteDatabse.insertWithOnConflict`. [Link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

> Returns the row ID of the newly
>   inserted row OR the primary key of the
>   existing row if the input param
>   'conflictAlgorithm' = CONFLICT_IGNORE
>   OR -1 if any errorOR -1 if any error

In older versions of SDK you can:

1. query if entry exists
2. If entry found - return id of selected item
3. If nothing found - insert entry using `SQLiteDatabse.insert` (it will return primary key of new item).

Also consider using transactions if needed.

Comment: I found that this API call doesn't work as expected. Shame. I'm also supporting back to 1.5.