# Can't stop table from autoincrement id when insert unique field

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with 2 columns, a numeric id and unique text. Created like this:

```
String CREATE_MY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEST + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
        + KEY_FOO + " TEXT UNIQUE" 
        + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_MY_TABLE);
```

I want that when I insert KEY_FOO value and it's already in the db, *nothing* happens. But what I get is that the id is always incremented. No new row is inserted, that's good, but the id is autoincremented.

What I'm doing to insert is as follows:

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_TEST , null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE);
```

I tried `CONFLICT_IGNORE`, `CONFLICT_ABORT`, `CONFLICT_ROLLBACK`, all the same.

The reason I need this is because other table has a foreign key on this id, thus if the id is changed, the other table points nowhere.

How I just say to let the existing entry untouched?

Comment: `CONFLICT_NONE`, `CONFLICT_IGNORE` (which you want), and `CONFLICT_ABORT` do *not* behave the same. Please ensure that you are testing correctly.

Comment: I mean that they behave the same concerning this. The first one I tested was IGNORE. I also wondered why it increments the id. I'm testing correctly, with database viewer, debugger, etc.

Comment: `CONFLICT_REPLACE` deletes the old record and then inserts the new one. No other conflict resolution method does this; if you're seeing this anyway, you're not executing the code you think you're executing.

Comment: I'm checking this before-after the line with IGNORE is executed. I see the id changes, so I assume it's replacing the row. In this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794579/finding-auto-incremented-values-from-an-insert-or-ignore-statement-in-sqlite there's a comment "I found that this API call doesn't work as expected. Shame. I'm also supporting back to 1.5." – jamesh - maybe related?

Comment: That talks just about the return value. How are you checking the ID?

Comment: I'm using Questoid - a plugin for SQLite in Eclipse: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/ I see the table with Questoid before and after the update-line, and the id is changed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. In your dbhelper class write the method like following to insert.

```
public int insertData(String desc) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        cv.put(KEY_FOO, desc);          
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_TEST, null, cv);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return 1;
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then from your actvity you call this method with the parameter value of `KEY_FOO`. This method will `return 1` if the exception is occurs (If you try insert a unique value) and it will `return 0` if the transaction is successfull.

I hope this way will help you. Let me know if any problem.